# json schema date validation not suitable for mongodb

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema

I'm using npm `jsonschema` module for nodejs and my very simple json schema looks like:

```
    "title": "ticket",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "_id"    : {"type": "string"},
        "created": {"type": "string", "format": "date-time"} 
    },
    "additionalProperties" : false
```

The data I validate through this schema is stored in mongodb. The problem is that created property has an index with expireAfterSeconds to auto delete these records after certain amount of time.

Now I have the following problem. If I send a string (no matter if it's valid or invalid according to json specification), the document in the database also has created property with type string, as mongo db is schemaless and I can't predefine that property as date type. For example if I send the data with created property as `2017-08-15T14:34:18.839Z` ISO string and although mongo date properties looks very similar they still remains string. Ofc this breaks the expires logic.

If I send my data with real date for created property, JSON validation fails with

```
instance.created is not of a type(s) string
```

Ofc I can transform all date fields on insert and update from validated string to date type but this is kinda not sufficient, because on read I will have data with real date types that will fail validation on next update. So I can include a back transformation on every read from date to string but still this solution is not good enough for me.

Any other ideas ?

Comment: does the date have to be a string? why can't you store it as "ISOdate" (mongodb's native date type)?  also do you have to do validation with json schema or can you replace it with doing validation in MongoDB itself?

Comment: It has to be a date even! The problem is that if I send a date as a date type json validation fails. The replacement of json schema validation is not possible for now, cause we use it for different databases, where there is not a built-in validation. For now I've made custom triggers on before save and after read, that deal with date fields.

Comment: Ok it's really more correct to store it as an actual date from MongoDB point of view but of course if other systems require a string that's an external thing.  You can enforce schema in MongoDB itself actually.

Answer (score 0):

Correct types for `_id` (which is ObjectID) and date types are:

```
"bsonType": "objectId" // for ObjectID
"bsonType": "date" // For ISODate
```

Example:

```
"title": "ticket",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "_id"    : {"bsonType": "objectId"},
        "created": {"bsonType": "date"} 
    },
    "additionalProperties" : false
```

Answer (score -1):

Not familiar with jsonschema but if you were to use [ajv](https://ajv.js.org) you could make use of custom keywords and validation such as:

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "someDate": {
      "instanceof": "Date"
    }
  }
}
```